# How to catch user's click on the android screen of any application?

Tags: android

Is it possible to write service that can catch any user's click on the touch screen and read text of the click no matter what application currently is active?
For example user click on browser  or any other application and that service will know what word is written in the location of the screen.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is a built in functionality to *select* and *copy* text, as you can see from this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ofQqhJ_fa2M&feature=player_embedded).

If you want to do it programatically, start reading on [ClipboardManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/ClipboardManager.html). However, I find it most unlikely that this will work on every application developed for Android.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick reply!
I think that I didn't explain myself correctly. What I want is service that run in background and monitor user's click from other applications.Regarding ClipboardManager, each application should implement and use this service in order to set text in the clipboard, I want catch it without the application. 

Thanks again!!!!!

Comment: You can always have a service running in the background, but whether your idéa tampers with user clicks in another application is something to find out. Looks interesting though. More to read on service (in background): http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

Comment: @BennySkogberg, I am also looking for the something similar to that. What i wish is to have one main activity; and one service which will starts when my application start and ends when application ends. And in service i want that it continuously check whether user has click any button or not of the main activity. I am having 10 buttons defined inside layout and declare variables of type button inside the main activity. If user has not click any button for particular time duration then i wish to play some animation. Can you please help me if you have any idea.